# JavaScript comparing two variables

Tags: javascript

```
     var userNam;
 var whoIsMove;
 var playerColor;
 var playerToMoveID;
 var currentPlayerID = $("#currentPlayerID").val();

 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
     //$("#moveMessage").html("Waiting for update...");
     var refreshId = setInterval("GetMoves(), GetWhoIsMove()", 1000);
     var to;
     var from = 's65';
     var pieceName;

     playerColor = $("#playerColor").val();
     currentPlayerID = $("#currentPlayerID").val();
     /// playerToMoveID = $("#playerToMove").val();

     if (currentPlayerID == playerToMoveID)
     {
         if (playerColor.toString() == "white")
         {
             $(".whiteP").draggable({
                 //revert: 'invalid',
                 //helper: 'clone',
                 cursor: 'move',
                 containment: 'checkerBoard',
                 start: function (event, ui)
                 {
                     //$(".square").hover(function ()
                     //{
                     //    from = $(this).attr('id')
                     //});
                     pieceName = $(this).attr('id');
                     //alert($from);
                 }
             });
         } else if (playerColor.toString() == "black")
         {
             $(".blackP").draggable({
                 //revert: 'invalid',
                 //helper: 'clone',
                 cursor: 'move',
                 containment: 'checkerBoard',
                 start: function (event, ui)
                 {
                     //$(".square").hover(function ()
                     //{
                     //    from = $(this).attr('id')
                     //});
                     pieceName = $(this).attr('id');
                     //alert($from);
                 }
             });
         }
     }
     $("div.square").droppable({
         accept: '.chessPiece',
         drop: function (event, ui)
         {
             to = $(this).attr('id');
             //alert(currentPlayerID);
             $.post(
            "/Game/MakeMove",
            {
                To: to,
                From: from,
                PieceName: pieceName,
                UserName: $("#userName").val(),
                UserID1: $("#userID1").val(),
                UserID2: $("#userID2").val(),
                GameID: $("#gameID").val()

            },
             function (data)
             {
                 if (data == 'good')
                 { }
                 else if (data == 'bad')
                 {
                     alert("sorry not you turn");
                 }
             }
            );

         }
     });
 })

function GetWhoIsMove()
{
                    $.getJSON(
                    "/Game/GetWhoIsMove",
                    {
                        GameID: $("#gameID").val()
                    },
                    function (data)
                    {
                        playerToMoveID = data;
                    }
                    );
}
```

That line is causing problems:
if (currentPlayerID == playerToMoveID)

It always return false. I have checked values, and currentPlayerID is depeding on what player is curretnly logged in and playerToMoveID is pulled up from data base.

While I used those variables in alert(), they showed correct values for both players. So I must ask, what's wrong with that if() ?

It should be alwyas true for exactly one player, until he make his move.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing the value of `playerToMoveID` before you set it.

You set the value of `playerToMoveID` as the result of a function call caused by the `setInterval`.

When the `if` statement fails, it's because the `if` statement is being evaluated before the `setInterval` has had a chance to fire.

You need to come up with a way to ensure that `playerToMoveID` is set before the `if` statement.  A `setInterval` won't cut it -- there's no guarantee that it will run in a timely manner.

The reason it "works" when you check the values is probably that you've changed the program enough that by the time you get to the second `alert` box that displays the `playerToMoveID` value, it's had a chance to run the `GetWhoIsMove` function.

Comment: I have check if(playerToMoveID != null), and it works fine, so I dont think this is an case, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are some extra spaces.
Why not try this:

```
if (jQuery.trim(currentPlayerID) == jQuery.trim(playerToMoveID))
```

Comment: == is evil. === is recommended. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've commented out the setting of `playerToMoveID`

`/// playerToMoveID = $("#playerToMove").val();`

Comment: I don't it is commented out in OP's actual code since he was able to test the values of both. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I would hope not. That really is a facepalm moment.

Comment: No playerToMoveID is set in function. I had it hardcoded and set from database but it proved to not working as intended ;p.

Comment: But you haven't called that function in the $(document).ready(). That variable will not get set at present.

Comment: I thought var refreshId = setInterval("GetMoves(), GetWhoIsMove()", 5000); this line will do.
GetWhoIsMove() is function that set this variable.

Comment: It does but you have to remember that javascript runs asynchronously. You have set the function to be called after 1 second and the comparison between the two variables will have been done before then without playerToMoveID being set.